# Missing values in the outcome of predict.glmnet

Tags: r, na, predict, glmnet

I've built a lasso model with `glmnet` function.

Then I try to use this model in the function `predict` with a test set of 28055 rows but the prediction output has only 25118 values. I guess it did not include `NA` values because the predictors in the test set have some missing values. I know that for the `glm` package one can deal with this with `na.action = na.pass` but it does not seem to exist in the `glmnet` package. Any suggestion ?

EDIT : my test does not have any missing values neither has my train set